# upload file using jquery and handler(ashx)

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, handler

I am trying to upload a file using jquery ajax with handler (c#). The problem is, when I call the handler I get

```
context.Request.File.Count=0
```

Here is the aspx code:

```
<!--aspx file code-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () 
{
    $('#save').click(function (e)
    {
        CalluploaderHandler();
    });
});

function CalluploaderHandler()
{
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/UPloader.ashx",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: OnComplete,
                error: OnFail
            });
    return false;
}

function OnComplete(result)
{
    alert('Success');
}

function OnFail(result)
{
    alert('Request failed');
}

</script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file">
                Filename:</label>
                <input name="file" id="file" type="file">
                <input id="save" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The c# code handler:

```
/* handler*/
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string savedFileName = "";

    foreach (string file in context.Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = context.Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
            continue;
        // savedFileName = context.Server.MapPath(Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        // hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
    }
    context.Response.Write(savedFileName);
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

i think the problem is with the `contentType` try

```
contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
```

OR

```
contentType :'application/octet-stream';
```

see this post for more information

[Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5392344/413670)

Answer (score 3):

You can add this kind of code to the handler file. Then you can post to this url(whateverroot/yourhandler.ashx)

The content type should be "multipart/form-data". 
For eg: 
If you're using a HTML form tag, then enctype="multipart/form-data".

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
        var result = "0";
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    file = context.Request.Files[i];
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(<somepath>, fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        result = "1"; 
                    }
                }    

            }
        }
        catch { }
      context.Response.Write(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services/UPloader.ashx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: OnComplete,
    error: OnFail
});
```

..is missing the `data` parameter. The way it's currently written, nothing is being sent to the handler.

You need to pass the file to the handler, using the `data` parameter.
Please have a go through this link: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/02/jquery-upload-images-files-without-page-refresh-postaback-in-aspnet.html