# How to get responsetext from a Page with Post method using XMLHttpRequest in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse, postfile

I have a `web page` which sends a `video file/blob` to **another web page** in the using `FormData` using `POST` method and `XMLHttpRequest`. I want to ***return the response as string*** from the `Posted URL` in calling function. i.e after successfull upload file i want to return string to the caller.

**index.aspx:**

```
function SendFile(blob)
{
var file = new File([blob], "testfile123.webm");
var oData = new FormData();
oData.append("file", file,"testfile.webm");
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "upload.aspx", true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) 
{
  if (oReq.status == 200) 
  {
    alert("Uploaded"+oReq.responseText);
  } 
  else {
    alert("Error");                     
  }
};
oReq.send(oData);
}
```

**Upload.aspx:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string folderPath = GetUploadFolderPath();
     string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss") + ".webm";  
     HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
     for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
     {
         HttpPostedFile postedFile = fileCollection[i];
         var filePath = folderPath + filename; //postedFile.FileName;
         postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

     }             
 }
```

In above code the file is created at specified location all works fine.I know its not possible in `Page_Load` event. please suggest correct method to send responsetext/string after file upload.

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Not really the issue here, but I recommend to use generic handlers **ashx** for data transfers instead of **aspx**. Usually one does not need the full life cycle (init, load, render, prerender, onerror) and webforms provided by **aspx** for fileuploads. There are examples on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466941/upload-file-using-jquery-and-handlerashx)

Comment: Just guessing here, but isn't it simply something like `Response.Write("some response");`?

Comment: @Lain Request.Files is not accessible in static method. :( also i need the response as text/string and do not want to write the response using Response.Write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **scraped** together example on how to target specific functions inside **aspx** with **jquery.ajax** using **vb.net**. Sadly I am not fluent in **C#**.

> Note that if you are using an ancient version of .net (two or lower), you have to add `System.Web.Extensions` in your *web.config* to make it work. Depending on the *IIS* either as `httpModules` or as `modules`.

### AJAX.aspx

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Function abc(def As String) As Boolean
    ''REM: Do stuff
    Return True
End Function
```

### xhr call using jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AJAX.aspx/abc",
    data: "{'def':'test'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response){...},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){...}
});
```

Yet, I still recommend to use generic handlers, like also shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466941/upload-file-using-jquery-and-handlerashx). It is more clean, slim and offers more control on what you actually want to do. Also the `System.Web.Extensions` are not required.